# Ruler Function definition and graphical representation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was just wondering if anyone would be able to explain what the Ruler Function is and how the sequences of numbers it generates. More specifically, I want to know how the function draws the markings on a ruler. Thanks in advance.

From what I know so far, the ruler function divides an inch equally in to $1/2$ to the $n$ pieces. Not sure if this knowledge is correct.

For example, the ruler function for $n=1$ generates $1$

$n = 2$ generates $1$ $2$ $1$

How are these numbers being generated and how do they represent the markings on a ruler ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several different definitions for what's known as the Ruler Function. One which is close to your intent is [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RulerFunction.html). In this definition, the function $r(n)$ returns the largest power, $k$ of 2 for which $2^k$ divides $2n$:
$$
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
n   & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & \dots \\ \hline
r(n)& 1 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 4 & \dots
\end{array}
$$
To draw a ruler with an inch divided into $2^m$ segments, just make marks with heights corresponding to $r(n)$ for $n=1, 2, \dots, 2^m-1$ and then add the outer marks with heights $m+1$.

For example, with $m=3$ you would place evenly-spaced marks of heights $1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1$ and add marks of height 4 around the ones you've made, giving you

```
   |                       |
   |           |           |
   |     |     |     |     |
   |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
   -------------------------
      1  2  1  3  1  2  1
```